# How to specify project version that only sbt publishLocal should use?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am switching my open source projects from `sbt-release` to `sbt-ci-release` in order to automate my releases.

Currently with sbt-release, it manages a `version.sbt` file which contains:

```
ThisBuild / version := <lastReleasedVersion>-SNAPSHOT
```

`sbt-release` updates this file as part of the release process, so any time I used `sbt publishLocal`, the project gets published locally with the **same consistent version number** (e.g. `0.1.3-SNAPSHOT`) until I release the project to Maven (e.g. as `0.1.3`), and then `sbt-release` updates the version in version.sbt to `0.1.4-SNAPSHOT`.

In contrast, `sbt-ci-release` is designed differently, and its docs tell me to remove any `version := ...` statements from my build.sbt, because it manages the version itself. Because of this, I had to delete the `version.sbt` file, and so now when I `publishLocal` the project locally, it gets published with a unique version number like `0.1.2+4-a5b1da75+20230103-2217-SNAPSHOT`. This version number includes the last git commit hash and a timestamp of the latest local change.

I don't want such a snapshot versioning scheme – it requires me to update the `build.sbt` file of the other local project that depends on this one every time I publishLocal a change. With the previous behaviour I only needed to `sbt reload` the consuming project to get the changes, now I need to also copy paste version numbers. I understand that more specific snapshot version numbers can be safer, but with local development I am optimizing for speed, not safety.

So my question is – how can release locally with a consistent SNAPSHOT version number that doesn't change on every commit, without manual busywork like typing `version := "whatever"` into sbt console? I want to keep using `sbt-ci-release` for production releases in CI (Github Actions) too.

Is there a way to use a custom version number with the `publishLocal` command specifically? There must be a way to build the custom sbt command / task that I need, but I just don't know how.

Comment: Personal opinion: sbt-ci-release is great when you start and don't need customisation but otherwise it's perfectly fine to keep your existing setup.

Comment: Update: I found sbt-dynver too confusing to work with directly, but someone already did exactly what I want for the Play framework. I ended up copying it for my project: https://github.com/raquo/Laminar/commit/21e44007a2e14189a58b4d3e1892398dafdcb4e1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sbt-ci-release uses [sbt-dynver](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-dynver) for the versioning.

You should be able to customize the version format according to their documentation at the cost of a bit of code in your projects.